# AWS storing simple array with 30 elements

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I am making an app in which I need to store an array of 30 elements (that's the only storage needed). I have a python script that updates these 30 elements every couple of seconds. I am wondering what the best AWS data storage would be for something like this. I tried Redis but Elasticache for Redis cost money, and I don't want to have to pay. Is there any way to use Redis on AWS *without* using Elasticache (which costs money)? Or is there any other way of storing this array on AWS without having to pay?

Comment: What is your app running on? How long do you need to store 30 elements for?

Comment: It's running on an EC2 instance. I need to store the 30 elements forever (pretty much), and I change the values every second or so in a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ideas that will be a lot cheaper than using Elasticache. You could store your data in:

- some file in a S3 bucket
- a DynamoDB table
- [SimpleDB](https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)
- [Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/)

My personal pick would be to start with S3 or DynamoDB and see how it fits your need.

Comment: The problem that I see with going the S3 route is that I am storing only one 30-element integer array (as well as one other integer variable) that I am writing to every 10 seconds, as from what I understand S3 is used more for storing big files (that don't get touched very often). I'm also not sure how good of a storage DynamoDB is because I am not using any tables.

Comment: You can store very small (or even empty) files in S3. The main benefit of using S3 instead of DynamoDB is that you won't run into throttling problems like is typically the case with a DynamoDB table.

Comment: And is it a problem that I would be accessing these S3 files every 5/10 seconds or so?

Comment: No absolutely not